# Separating truthy and falsey values from an object

Tags: javascript, function, loops, object

I'm working on a java challenge that reads

```
//In the function below you'll be passed a user object. Loop through the user object checking to make sure that each value is truthy. If it's not truthy, remove it from the object. Then return the object. hint: 'delete'.

function truthyObjLoop(user) {
  //code here
```

I came up with....

```
  var user = {};
  user.name = {};
  user.age = {};


  if (user !== false)
  {
   return user; 
  } else {
    delete user;
  }

}
```

However whenever I try it it comes back with the error Function returned 
{"name":{},"age":{}}
instead of 
{"name":"ernest","age":50}
when passed 
{"name":"ernest","age":50,"funky":false}....

Can anyone help me understand why this is happening or if I'm using the wrong symbols here?  Thank you.

Comment: @J. Lago This is  javascript. First make sure what u need. Then be clear with your question and ask it in an understandable way.

Comment: It looks like the `user` parameter of `function truthyObjLoop` has been redefined in the function by defining a variable with the same name. This will prevent the function from accessing the parameter actually passed. Please also do some research on javascript's `for...in` loop syntax as well as the `delete` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

```
var user = {};
user.name = {};
user.age = {};
```

The user name and age should be the values, not Objects. curly braces mentions objects, you are wrong.try my following code please

```
var user = {};
user.name = "john";
user.age = 12;
```

Also read this tutorial please : 
http://www.w3schools.com/json/

Comment: That didn't seem to work. Although thank you for pointing out the curly braces thing there.  I'm still very new to programming as my noob showing could probably tell you.

What could I put in that field to leave it blank for user input?

Comment: i think you should be like this user = { "name": "john","age" : 20} and verify your code please. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The text says "you'll be passed a user object".  That means the user is being defined outside of the function, and passed in.  Here's what you're looking for:

```
function truthyObjLoop(user) {
    for (var k in user) {
        if (!user[k]) delete user[k]
    }
    console.log(user);
}
```

You then should pass in a "user" with all sorts of different attributes to demonstrate how the test works:

```
var person = {
    age: 29,
    gender: "male",
    pets: [
        {
            type: "cat",
            name: "smelly"
        }
    ],
    children: 0,
    married: false
};

truthyObjLoop(person);
```

Here's a jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mckinleymedia/tb823pyp/

Notice it removes the attributes with a value of 'false' or '0'.